# Can't connect to remote server using RDP remmina after upgrade

Tags: certificates, remmina, rdp

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu to 18.04, and now my Remmina cannot connect to a windows server we use at work. Now I am getting a popup about certificates.  It asks if I want to accept the certificate,  I click OK and then get a message saying unable to connect.  I am getting this error on the command line:

```
[14:49:19:412] [7223:7537] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx cliprdr
[14:49:19:412] [7223:7537] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx drdynvc
[14:49:19:909] [7223:7537] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[14:49:19:909] [7223:7537] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - @           WARNING: CERTIFICATE NAME MISMATCH!           @
[14:49:19:909] [7223:7537] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[14:49:19:909] [7223:7537] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - The hostname used for this connection (xxxxx:3389) 
[14:49:19:909] [7223:7537] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - does not match the name given in the certificate:
[14:49:19:909] [7223:7537] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - Common Name (CN):
[14:49:19:909] [7223:7537] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] -    EC2AMAZ-FM25IO2
[14:49:19:909] [7223:7537] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - A valid certificate for the wrong name should NOT be trusted!
[14:50:38:624] [7223:7537] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - certificate not trusted, aborting.
[14:50:38:624] [7223:7537] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_set_last_error ERRCONNECT_CONNECT_CANCELLED [0x0002000B]
[14:50:38:624] [7223:7537] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.connection] - Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
0002000B 00000003
```

Now this is an internal  vpn server so I don't care at all about certificates.  Is there a way to add this certificate to a list that it's ok?  How do I get around this?  And as an aside, this was working before the upgrade just fine. I don't know why it cares now?

Comment: This has already been fixed a while ago, I think, try a new version from the corresponding PPA

Comment: so i added the ppa:  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next   and then did a sudo apt-get install remmina  and I still get the same error

Comment: Does selecting TLS from advanced options fix it?

Comment: Running as sudo seems to fix it.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem on debian sid with latest remmina 1.2.32.1 while connecting to a windows server2008r2 with hardend security settings.

I was able to connect after:

- updating all freerdp2 libraries (used by remmina) to 2.0.0~git20181120.1 version
- removing ~/.config/freerdp/known_hosts2 file

The connection security type that worked is "NLA" (negotianion/auto-detection worked too).

Both TLS and RDP didn't work.

Comment: NLA worked for me on 'default' ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What worked for me was deleting known_hosts2 file. I think something changed in the server and couldn't verify the fingerprint.

Answer (score 7):

I've found the solution @Ubuntu forums, that forked for me :)

You have to change the Security to "TLS" in the Advanced tab of your connection, and everything works fine!

Comment: Don't hesitate to provide the link of the answer you've found.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: I also ran as sudo and that worked too.

Answer (score 4):

with RDP connections I get a TLS connection error, you have to look to the correct TLS version:

for me the solution was other way around:

I have to change the Security to "RDP" in the Advanced tab of your connection, and everything works fine!
( I work with debian 10 buster (sid) and remmina 1.2.32)
regards,
from germany

Comment: After saving it as RDP (or anything else), it always immediately reverts back to Negotiate.  Remmina 1.4.1 (git v1.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

I've hit the same problem connecting from one of the Ubuntu/Debian family distributive to MS Windows Server 2008 R2.

I managed to solve it this way:

1. Create new connection with server.name.or.ip:port in Server section (port is optional if u haven't changed it from standard MS RDP 3389 or/and NATed it through a router if u have one)
2. In the Advanced tab set
   -"Security protocol negotiation" to "NLA protocol security"
   -"TLS Security level" to "0 -- Windows 7 compatible"

Then Remmina only asked me once about accepting the certificate and now it works like a charm.